# App closes once started when loaded for Appium test

Tags: ios, appium, xcode8

I have created a simple app using one of the templates in XCode 8.1 so that I can test a script written for Appium.

I have built an archive and passed it to a small Python script. After I start Appium and run the script, the simulator opens, install the WebDriverAgent, then my simple app. However, the simple app appears to open but immediately closes and shows the simulator's home screen.

Once the script is finished, if I try and open the app again in the simulator it continues to close immediately.

Does anyone know why this is happening? And what can I do to correct the problem?

The python script is:

```
from appium import webdriver
import os


app_path = "/path/to/app/simpleApp.ipa"
udid = "ios_simulators_udid"
platformVersion = "10.0"
deviceName = "iPhone 6"

success = True 
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = platformVersion
desired_caps['deviceName'] = deviceName
desired_caps['udid'] = udid
desired_caps['automationName'] = 'XCUITest'
desired_caps['realDeviceLogger'] = 'idevicesyslog'
desired_caps['app'] = app_path

wd = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
wd.implicitly_wait(60)

try:
    wd.find_element_by_xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='OK']").click()
    wd.find_element_by_xpath("//XCUIElementTypeTextField[1]").send_keys("123")
finally:
    wd.quit()
    if not success:
        raise Exception("Test failed.")
```

Comment: What error message do you get from Appium node?

Comment: None that I can find. In a terminal where appium is outputting logs it is hanging. I have looked in the console and cannot see anything to do with appium or the simulator.

Comment: I should qualify what I meant by hanging. Appium has a line saying it is starting the app. Even after the app has closed. It does not do anything until it times out and closes the connection.

Comment: Check are you using the correct .app file

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51443937/1522584